# VBA Insert two list box values into a table

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba, do-while

I have two list boxes on my form.
For each item selected in ConceptList, I need to add all selected items in ParkList

The attached Desired State image shows what I would expect when Two selections were made in the ConceptList and four in the ProspectList. The Current State shows the result of the code below

[Current State Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOWW1.png)
[Desired State Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLfiR.png)

```
  Dim db As Database
   Dim rs As Recordset

   Set db = CurrentDb()
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblFinal")
   For Each itm In ConceptList.ItemsSelected
        rs.AddNew
        rs!ConceptID = ConceptList.ItemData(itm)
        rs!ParkID = ParkList.ItemData(itm)
        rs.Update
  Next

  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an inner loop as well:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblFinal")

For Each concept In ConceptList.ItemsSelected
    For Each park In ParkList.ItemsSelected
        rs.AddNew
            rs!ConceptID = ConceptList.ItemData(concept)
            rs!ParkID = ParkList.ItemData(park)
        rs.Update
    Next
Next   
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Ah.. That's it. Thank you for your help